# how to store const value in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I'm trying to create a random name for project and store it in a variable, and fetching the same value in other files..My problem is while creating project name a random value say( const Name = 'MyName-' + randomName) i.e Name = 'MyName-abcd' is generated by while fetching new value is generated like Name = 'MyName-efgh' while fetching also it is generating a random value.

I tried to use const to store and also used to local storage to getItem both the case i'm getting different value

I want random name once and use the same generated name in all files.

```js
construct.js

class ConstructPage {

  // Constants.real_PROJECT_NAME + this.randomName(5)
  randomName(length) {

    var result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;

  }

}


export default ConstructPage;




constant.js

export const random_Name = new ConstructPage().randomName(5);
export const real_PROJECT_NAME = 'cypress-budgeting-' + random_Name;
export const fetch_project_Name = localStorage.setItem('real_api_project_name', real_PROJECT_NAME);
export const get_project_Name = localStorage.getItem('real_api_project_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

First time you are generating a random name and storing it in local storage so what happened next time again it will generate a new name and will update in local storage that's why you are getting different name each time.

So generate random name once and store it in local storage and next time access that name from local storage but don't generate name again.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to generate a random name once and return it whenever randomName is called. To do this, you can create a static variable attached to the randomName function.

```
randomName(length) {
    if (randomName.result) {
        return randomName.result;
    }

    randomName.result = '';
    var characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      randomName.result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return randomName.result;
}
```

Since the function is an object, it can have properties which persist between executions. If you want to have different names for different lengths, you can make your property an object which maps a length to a name and check whether a mapping exists before generating a new name.